# How to trace errors one by one from the build-output reported by TeXnicCenter?

Tags: errors, compiling, texniccenter

The problem I have at the moment is that, after the execution of "Build current file", TeXnicCenter displays a window (named *Build output*) in which you can read a short description of errors; each of them is "marked" by a white cross in a red disk. I don't see any information on the location of the errors in the text.

How can I find them in a pretty long text-file (more than 1100 lines)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 2):

With the LaTeX toolbar you can use the "Next Error (<kbd>F9</kbd>)" and "Previous Error (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)" buttons to jump from one error to the next/previous.

[image]

The same goes for jumping between warnings and bad boxes.

Answer (score 0):

This window is a text window. Every TeX error is marked `!`. So you can simply inside the window search consequtive `!`'s. Searching the *.log file is a general solution, independent of an editor used to a work with TeX.